# Backtrack in Possesive Quantifier

Tags: java, regex, regex-greedy

Earlier I posted a question about regex which resulted in stackoverflow error in java. My Regex was greedy and many commented to use possessive quantifier in regex. So, I started learning Possessive quantifier in regex.

I tried to match string between double quotes. My regex is

```
"([^\\"]|\\.)++"
```

I tried to match the string

```
"Hello I am \" chitti"
```

While matching there was backtracks. I tested using http://regex101.com/#PCRE. The link to regex is [REGEX 101 LINK](http://regex101.com/r/eL0uG6)

[image]

Can someone please explain why there is a backtrack involved steps 6,8,10 etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There shouldn't be a backtrack there. I would expect (and RegexBuddy shows) backtracks at the `\"` and at the final `"`, but not in these positions.

[image: RegexBuddy screenshot]

Perhaps regex101.com displays a `BACKTRACK` message also when the regex engine explicitly discards a potential backtracking position, but that's only speculation on my part.